# C# ORM samples for many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#-3.0

Where can I have good samples of object relational mapping scenarios for many to many relationship?

Comment: The generic model diagrams should be OK. If it is implementation-specific, I prefer ADO.NET Entity Framework and NHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how [many-to-many relationships](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues) work with NHibernate.